# Implementing Junits using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write Junits for webservices.The webservice is implemented via 3 layers.

Webservice -> Implementation layer -> Dao layer.

Implementation layer actually converts DAO Object to business object and passes that back to the service.

My aim is to write Junits for the service layer. Now, to achieve this I am mocking the values in the implementation layer using @Mock and @InjectMocks as the implementation layer is using spring annotated fields. But I get a null pointer exception everytime I test. Below are the code

**Service Layer**

```
@Override
    public FicheSolvaDetailDTO consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(Long numFicheSolva) throws MetierException, TechniqueException {
        try {

            LOGGER.info("Consultation de la fiche de solvabilité triennale n° " + numFicheSolva);
            return boToMessageConverter.convertFicheSolvabiliteDetaillee(manager.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(numFicheSolva));

        } catch (com.accord.contrat.business.exception.MetierException e) {
            throw new MetierException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (com.accord.contrat.business.exception.TechniqueException e) {
            throw new TechniqueException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

This then goes to the next layer.

```
@Override
    public FicheSolvaDetailDTO consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(Long numFicheSolva) throws MetierException, TechniqueException {
        try {

            LOGGER.info("Consultation de la fiche de solvabilité triennale n° " + numFicheSolva);
            return boToMessageConverter.convertFicheSolvabiliteDetaillee(manager.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(numFicheSolva));

        } catch (com.accord.contrat.business.exception.MetierException e) {
            throw new MetierException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (com.accord.contrat.business.exception.TechniqueException e) {
            throw new TechniqueException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Now comes the DAO Layer which I am not posting.

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SolvabiliteWSImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private static SolvabiliteWSImpl mockedSolvabiliteWSImpl;
    private static FicheSolvabiliteDetailBO ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO;

    @Mock
    IFicheSolvaManager managera;
    @Mock
    BOToMessageConverter boToMessageConverter;

    @Mock
    MessageToBOConverter messageToBo;

     @Before
    public void initMocks(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws MetierException, TechniqueException{

        ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO = new FicheSolvabiliteDetailBO();
        ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setCodeSituationFamilialeSouscripteur("1");
        ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setCodeSituationLocativeFoyer("1");
        ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setNumCommercant(705l);
        ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setNumEngagement(44686301l);
        ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setNumFicheSolva(138553l);

        when(managera.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(138553l)).thenReturn(ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO);

    }



    @Test
    public void testConsulterFicheSolvaDetailDTO() throws MetierException, TechniqueException{
        long numFicheSolve = 138553l;
        assertNotNull(mockedSolvabiliteWSImpl.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(numFicheSolve));
}
```

But it is not mocking the value, as in

when(managera.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(138553l)).thenReturn(ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO);

it should return me ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO when the above method is called. But the function further goes inside this method and then gives me null pointer exception which means it is not mocking?

Please suggest a possible way to test.

Comment: Which line of your code is throwing the exception?  A stack trace would be really helpful to anyone trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Assertion error at: assertNotNull method in the test class and I am getting
MockitoJunitRunner.run() error.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said you were getting a null pointer exception, not just a failed assertion.  It looks like you're not stubbing `boToMessageConverter.convertFicheSolvabiliteDetaillee` at all.  A method call on a mock will generally return null or zero if you haven't stubbed it (with a handful of exceptions).  Then that same null is getting returned by `consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale`.

Comment: Ok, I was earlier getting null pointer exception but after @Adam Michalik response I removed static from the test class but now I am getting InvocationTargetException. I will look what stubbing in Junit is and get back to you in like 30minutes. Thanks for the reposnse. :)

Comment: The line `when(managera.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(138553l)).thenReturn(ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO);` is stubbing.  But you also want to stub `boToMessageConverter.convertFicheSolvabiliteDetaillee`.  And I plan to be asleep 30 minutes from now.

Comment: But, If I make stub of that method as well or mock it, then what is the use of junits. Everything is mocked so what do I test it? I want only that part to be mocked which I want. Awake now?

Answer (score 2):

a) You have

```
@InjectMocks
private static SolvabiliteWSImpl mockedSolvabiliteWSImpl;
```

on a static field. This does not work - change it to an instance field. JUnit wil anyway create a new instance for each test run.

b) You don't need

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

when you're using

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

just either one of them. As @crea1 wrote - the order of `@Before`s is undetermined, so better to simply delete the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: I did that but I am now getting some other error, Invocation target exception is what I am getting. Can you tell what is the possible reason for it?

Comment: Not without a stacktrace and more details.

Comment: So when the control goes to the below mentioned line:  
return boToMessageConverter.convertFicheSolvabiliteDetaillee(manager.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(numFicheSolva));

I have mocked just manager.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(numFicheSolva) and not the boToMessageConverter.convertFicheSolvabiliteDetaillee. Can that create a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `@Before` methods. JUnit can't guarantee that `initMocks()` is called before `setUp()`. Therefor the Mock might not yet be initialized in the `setUp()` method. It is better to have a single `@Before` method like this to guarantee the mocks are initialized:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws MetierException, TechniqueException {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO = new FicheSolvabiliteDetailBO();
    ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setCodeSituationFamilialeSouscripteur("1");
    ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setCodeSituationLocativeFoyer("1");
    ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setNumCommercant(705l);
    ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setNumEngagement(44686301l);
    ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO.setNumFicheSolva(138553l);

    when(managera.consulterFicheSolvabiliteTriennale(138553l)).thenReturn(ficheSolvabiliteDetailBO);

}
```